# spring.net dependency injections in the dynamic data project

Tags: asp.net, spring.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am trying to use spring.net for dependency injection in the asp.net dynamic data project. Spring is configured correct because service locator pattern works.

I configured spring as for web.forms project, but dependency injection doesn't work for dynamic pages.

Does anyone know how to make injections to the dynamic pages?

**Edit:**
Looks that problem in the asp.net routing. Dynamic data framework uses routing for process dynamic pages.
According to the next link spring.net can't work with routings yet.

http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?7306-Asp.Net-Routing-in-web-form-and-missing-injection

Comment: Are there any other (non-dynamic) pages in the web project for which DI works?

Comment: @Marijn Yes. I created non-dynamic test page (Test.aspx). Injection works for it.